# abric go sdk1.0.0 execute [cli.Execute()] get an error "error registering for TxStatus event: no peers to connect to"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

When I use fabric go sdk1.0.0 to access the fabric network and execute [cli.Execute()] and try to write data, I get an error "error registering for TxStatus event: no peers to connect to"

I can guarantee that my sdk can access the peer node normally, because I will not report an error when I execute [cli.Query()] to obtain data.

And when [cli.Execute()] is executed, the log information of the accessed peer node indicates that it has already run the chaincode.
The peer log is as follows

```
2023-04-14 05:08:11.934 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0b0 [appchannel][a50fb576] Entry chaincode: name:"cscc" 
2023-04-14 05:08:11.935 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0b1 [appchannel][a50fb576] Exit chaincode: name:"cscc"  (0ms)
2023-04-14 05:08:11.935 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0b2 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.request_deadline=2023-04-14T05:11:11.929Z grpc.peer_address=172.27.0.1:51606 grpc.peer_subject="CN=Admin@org2.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.276016ms
2023-04-14 05:08:11.938 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0b3 [appchannel][11c6e1a1] Entry chaincode: name:"fabric-realty" 
2023-04-14 05:08:11.939 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0b4 [appchannel][11c6e1a1] Exit chaincode: name:"fabric-realty"  (1ms)
2023-04-14 05:08:11.940 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0b5 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.request_deadline=2023-04-14T05:11:11.938Z grpc.peer_address=172.27.0.1:51606 grpc.peer_subject="CN=Admin@org2.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.875217ms
```

And I can use the cli node to read and write to the fabric network, and only report an error when using the sdk access

If you need more information, I'll be more than happy to provide it. Thank you for your help!